# Convert containers via constructor

Tags: c++, stl

Suppose I have classes

```
class A {
   //...
};

struct B {
   explicit B(const A&);
   //...
};
```

and I have a container of A's, from which I would like to construct a container of B's.  What is an idiomatic way to do this in c++ 03?

Tried and failed:

```
std::vector<A> source = fillSourceObjects();
std::vector<B> target;

// 1) won't compile; presumably I need a static helper function, 
//    but I would like to avoid that
std::transform(source.begin(), source.end(), std::back_inserter(target), B);
std::transform(source.begin(), source.end(), std::back_inserter(target), B::B);

// 2) won't compile; "... error: no match for 'operator=' in '* __result = *__first'
std::copy(source.begin(), source.end(), target.begin());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert a sequence of `A`s into a sequence of `B`s using the `std::vector<T>` constructor taking a sequence:

```
std::vector<B> target(source.begin(), source.end());
```

Comment: That's about as idiomatic as it gets :)